# Applying convolution on individual layers using keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a pretrained VGG16 network and I modified the network for PASCAL VOC 2012 dataset using transfer learning. Now, I want to take the output of every layer from the modified VGG16 network and apply convolution on each layer, then upsample them to the same size and add them. This is to identify the important regions in the image. I have taken the output from every layer

```
output = [layer.output for layer in model.layers]
```

Now I want something like

```
hypercolumns = []
for op in output:
            #apply convolution on this output layer 
            #upsample it to the size of the input image
            #store this in hypercolumns list
```

Finally after all the layers are upsampled, I will add them from the list to get a single matrix. Now, I am confused on how to apply convolution without creating a model and do upsampling. Is there a way in keras.

Comment: `Now, I am confused on how to apply convolution without creating a model and do upsampling.`. What's wrong with creating a model for this purpose?

Comment: @hushv89 I want that for every layer, so in that case i will create too many models (one model for one layer in outputs list), and also I have to compile and train that model in one loop which I thought is not a good approach.

Comment: You might want to look in to `Lambda` layer in Keras. You can use Keras backend functions to achieve what you're trying to do. I don't you'll have to create multiple models using a `Lambda` layer. Just one model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this, some of which are listed [here in the Keras FAQ](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer). I don't know of any significant difference between the two main ways listed there, so try both and see what works. Here is an example of what you can do:

```
input = model.layers[0].input
for op in output:
    intermediate_function = K.function([input], [output])
    layer_output = intermediate_function([YOUR_INPUT_DATA_HERE])[0]
    # do the upsampling and stuff here
```